# Decoupling Authorization Server & Resource SErver using OWIN Middleware and Web API/MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin

the below process which i have followed while implementing single sign on

- Decoupled Authorization server & Resource server
- Got access-token using client_credentials from Authorization server

Problem:

- i have used mvc 4 application for resource server and can't able to access views(resource) from resource server using mvc controllers with Authorize Attribute
- used access-token generated by authorization server

also read the below question:

"I have an un-secured MVC 5/Web API 2 application. It accesses resources using a combination of MVC controllers, and ajax calls to the Web API endpoints.

Eventually I would like to move all resource access into a separate Resource Server. However, for the time being, I would like to get the application into production as a proof of concept for a line of business applications secured using the OAuth 2 framework.

I have configured users in IdentityServer, and added the application to AuthorizationServer using a code flow client. Based on the sample provided with the AS code, I am able to retrieve an access token in the application, add it to the request headers for Web API endpoint calls secured with the Scope attribute.

My questions is how can I utilize this same flow to secure the MVC controllers? I imagine it would entail setting up an OWIN middleware component which will set the authorization headers for each request based on a cookie which contains the token. Am I on the right path, or should I go in a different direction with this?"

please let me know how to access the mvc resource using owin middleware instead of web api.